# Angular child call parent function then parent pass data to child

Tags: angular, input, output, parent-child, eventemitter

What I want to do is if child component call parent component's function, parent will pass some data to child.
But the problem now is like in this example, even if the parent's function is called 5 times, as the data passed has no change, the child can't detect.
What I can to achieve is no matter the data from parent is modified or not, the child can be stilled notified from the parent and has the correct data.

Child.ts

```
@Input() set dataFromParent(v:any){
    console.log(v)
}
@Output() callParentFunction = new EventEmitter<any>()
ngOnInit() {
    for(let i = 0; i< 5;i++){
        this.callParentFunction.emit()
    }
}
```

Parent.html

```
<app-child (callParentFunction)="test()" [dataFromParent]="isData"/>
```

Parent.ts

```
isData = true
test=()=>{
    this.isData = true
}
```

Comment: your child component called 5 times in few milliseconds at last we can see the final output only

Comment: @Gopal No, the child component is not called 5 times, cause the variable passed is not modified and will not trigger the set function